# Wordpress: Outputting shortcode with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

```
<script language=”javascript”>
if (country_code==’US’)
{
document.write("[adrotate banner="1"]");
}
else
{
document.write("[adrotate banner="2"]");
}
</script>
```

`[adrotate banner="x"]` are wordpress shortcodes used for the Adrotate plugin

This script doesen't work because somehow outputting `[adrotate banner="x"]` is not possible?
It uses the globally saved variable `country_code`.

I've tried with both `"` and `'` (and the inner using one of them and the outer the other), but with no luck.

Any way to work around this and still use JS?

Answer (score 3):

Shortcodes only work server side. If you want to work around it, you can submit the value using AJAX, call `do_shortcode()` on it in your PHP, return the results as JSON, and then write to the page.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode

As a side note, your example has a syntax error because you have double quotes inside your string, since it won't process as a shortcode. You either need to escape it or use single quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the response! So the only way around this is to use PHP? I`ve got a script that doing the same thing i was trying in JS, but I don`t know how to globally save the variable $country_code, so that I can use it several times in a post or page, without having to load the geoip.inc and GeoIP.dat all the time.

How would I set this up in the header and save the variable for later use? 

Will using PHP in pages in Wordpress slow things down? Should I use Exec-PHP for this?

Thanks so much! Help is much appreciated!

Comment: `code`<?php
require_once(“geoip.inc”);
$gi = geoip_open(“GeoIP.dat”,GEOIP_STANDARD);
$country_code = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
geoip_close($gi);
if($country_code == ‘US’ || $country_code == false)
{
echo adrotate_group(1);
}
else
{
echo adrotate_group(2);
}
?>`code`

Comment: Use the code in your comment to implement a JSON request, the geoip stuff is all done on the server. You can use this as a guide http://justin.ag/technology/creating-ajax-functions-in-wordpress/, but note that it has to originate from the same domain. If you want to do it from a different domain, you will have to use JSONP.

Comment: Appreciated for suggesting to use the built in method!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use ` backtick (Template literals) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals?retiredLocale=it

```
<script language=”javascript”>
var option1 = `[adrotate banner="1"]`;
var option2 = `[adrotate banner="2"]`;

if (country_code=='US') {
    document.write(option1);
} else {
    document.write(option2);
}
</script>
```

also work with php code (workaround for single and double quote) :

```
<script language=”javascript”>
var option1 = `<?php echo do_shortcode('[adrotate banner="1"]'); ?>`;
var option2 = `<?php echo do_shortcode('[adrotate banner="2"]'); ?>`;

if (country_code=='US') {
    document.write(option1);
} else {
    document.write(option2);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks to Andrea Ciocca (https://stackoverflow.com/story/andreaciocca)