# Rendering a Wordpress shortcode with Javascript from a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, wordpress

I'm currently working on a Wordpress site. I'm building a custom plugin that allows for lazy loading of custom post types.

Some of these post types contain shortcodes, that I need to display. I have a primary Javascript file that makes Ajax requests to my PHP code in my plugin, which returns a JSON object containing the shortcode like this:

`Object {shortcode: "[embedyt]https://www.youtube.com/watch?&height=300[/embedyt]"}`

I'm then trying to display this shortcode on the front-end, since I'm dynamically building HTML blocks based on the JSON response.

However, when I try to output the shortcode to the page via the Javascript, it just displays as text, like this:

[image]

Here's my PHP code and Javascript:

```
$packet = array();
$formatted_url = "[embedyt]" . $youtube_root . $video_id . "&height=300" . "[/embedyt]";
$packet["shortcode"] = do_shortcode($formatted_url);
echo json_encode($packet); // This sends a response back to the Ajax request
```

And:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: tlas_lazy_load.ajax_url,
        data: {
            action: 'tlas_lazy_load',
            post_type: post_type,
            posts_per_page: 6,
            paged: page
        },
        success: function(packet) {
            response = JSON.parse(packet);
            for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                build_lazy_load("#lazy-load-row", packet[i], i);
            }
        }
    });

function build_lazy_load(element, packet, index) {
    var block = "";
    block += "<div class=\"col-md-4\">";
    block += "  <div class=\"video-individual\">";
    block += "      <div class=\"panel panel-default\">";
    block += "          <div class=\"panel-body\" id=" + index + ">";
    block +=                packet.shortcode;
    block += "          <\/div>";
    block += "      <\/div>";
    block += "  <\/div>";
    block += "<\/div>";
    $(element).append(block);
};
```

What gives me hope that this can be done is the answer to this question:

[Wordpress: Outputting shortcode with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16304706/wordpress-outputting-shortcode-with-javascript)

And I'm following along with what that person suggested. However can this be done?

**Update:**

So I can display the shortcode if I do this in enqueue scripts method:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tlas_lazy_load_enqueue_scripts' );
function tlas_lazy_load_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'tlas-lazy-load', plugins_url( 'js/tlas_lazy_load.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
    wp_localize_script( 'tlas-lazy-load', 'tlas_lazy_load', array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
        // BELOW
        'videos_shortcode' => do_shortcode("[embedyt]" . $youtube_root . $video_id . "&height=300" . "[/embedyt]")
        ));
}
```

By setting it as a localized variable which my Javascript can access. The problem is that I have to add the shortcode after this function has already been declared. I tried localizing it later within the file in my above function by doing:

```
...
$packet = array();
$formatted_url = "[embedyt]" . $youtube_root . $video_id . "&height=300" . "[/embedyt]";
wp_localize_script( 'tlas-lazy-load', 'tlas_lazy_load', array(
    'videos_shortcode' => do_shortcode($formatted_url)
));
...
```

But this didn't work, it simply returned nothing. I'm on the right track (I think?) but I'm not sure how you can dynamically localize a script/Javascript variable.

Comment: Your json should not contain any shortcodes as they should have been processed when you do: `$packet["shortcode"] = do_shortcode($formatted_url);`

Comment: You do know that you can use single quotes too? Instead of escaping every quote? But since shortcodes can do a lot of stuff, I see that your only real option is "rendering" it server side. Make a page that takes shortcode as input and return the value.

Comment: @Christina, I know. I just prefer to escape so as to keep the quotations uniform.

Comment: @jeroen What do you mean they "should have been processed"?